# Hibernate: Cannot Delete Object - foreign key constraint - CascadeType.REMOVE

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have two persistable entities Obj1 and Obj2. Obj2 contains a reference to Obj like below. There is no reference (at code level - Java) to Obj2 in Obj1.

```
public class Obj2{
....
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE}, optional = true)
private Obj1 obj1;
```

I updated Ojbj 1 with @OneToMany as suggested:

```
public class Obj1{

....

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE,CascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Obj2> obj2;
```

When I try to delete Obj1:

```
em.remove(obj1Instance)
```

It fails due to Foreigh Key constaint

```
00:35:23,109 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffff7f000101:-7f20c644:5369716f:26, org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization@dcedf7 >: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`my_db`.`obj2`, CONSTRAINT `FKC4783505BB5D6339` FOREIGN KEY (`obj1_pk`) REFERENCES `obj1` (`pk`))
...
... 94 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`my_db`.`obj2`, CONSTRAINT `FKC4783505BB5D6339` FOREIGN KEY (`obj1_pk`) REFERENCES `obj1` (`pk`))

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`my_db`.`obj2`, CONSTRAINT `FKC4783505BB5D6339` FOREIGN KEY (`obj1_pk`) REFERENCES `obj1` (`pk`))
```

I had (wrongly it seems!) asumed that CascadeType.REMOVE would take care of this? How should I handle this delete?

/T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys... I managed to do it by (sort of ) combining both pieces of advice and I altered the Foreign Key so that it would CASCADE on DELETE.

Answer (score 1):

Either handle it manually or add a reverse relationship `@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)` in Obj1.

Comment: I added the @OneToMany as suggested (see updated code above) but it still fails for the same reason "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails ...constraint..."

Comment: Are you sure there no other relationships between the DB tables, other then that one?

Comment: I will confirm later. Perhaps issue is the FK constraint that existed before i introduced the @ONeToMany is still causing the issue?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When did you add `optional = true`? Is it before deploying the application or after? If it is after, MySQL wouldn't update the NotNull constraint on `my_db`.`obj2`, check if column `obj1_pk` is Nullable. If it is not, drop and add the constraint `FKC4783505BB5D6339` so it can be Nullable.
Or you can simply drop these two tables and recreate them.

Comment: i can't drop any tables as i must add this feature to an existing DB

Comment: you can just adjust the FK relationship without dropping the db , is the column my_db.obj2.obj1_pk NULLABLE ?

Comment: it should be nullable since OPTIONAL is true, the exception is fired by Mysql, modify your constraint and it should work.